# Ошибка при установке MySQL server

Tags: mysql, windows-10

Пытаюсь установить MySQL server на windows 10 x64. Любая установка заканчивается ошибкой (скрин).
Скачал установщик версии 8.0.20 (последний), пробовал на 8.0.17 (у кого-то на этой версии получилось). Перепробовал 3 версии сервера. Запускал через инструменты "службы" этот сервер. Полностью переустанавливал MySQL. Все тщетно.
Что можно попробовать еще сделать?

Лог об ошибке: `MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. Failed to connect to MySQL Server 8.0.20 after 10 attempts`

[image: Сама ошибка]

Comment: Смотрите: имеется ли служба, запустилась ли она? Смотрите, что в логах, или хотя бы на вкладке Log, как предлагает инсталлятор.

Comment: Как я понимаю из сообщения в логах `Successfully started service MySQL80` (дальше идут попытки подключения с `ошибкой MySQL error 1042`), служба запустилась. В службах она тоже отображается